# open android app using scheme not working

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent

I feel stupid as I have found three different questions which seem to be the same as mine, but I can't get it to work.  I tried "Open Android app using intent-filter not working", "Open Android app from URL using intent-filter not working", and "Open Android app from URL using intent-filter not working for 4.1 version 2". My app captures activity on my mobile web site using a WebView, but I know a lot of my users use Google to launch their browser.  I would like instead for it to launch my app.  In addition, it would be nice when a user types the address of my site into a browser, they would get a selection dialog to give them the option of using my app for my web site.  My Manifest has the following:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="www.tennisrecruiting.net" />
            <!--<data android:pathPattern="/.*" />-->
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I have tried it with and without the commented out line, and with the pattern ".*" but none of them work.  That is, if I type "tennisrecruiting" into a google search, and click on a choice that takes me to "http://tennisrecruiting.net", the phone goes directly to my Chrome browser without asking to use my app.  Similarly, if I am in my chrome browser and type "http://tennisrecruiting.net" as the target URL, chrome just opens my site without launching my app or asking the user for a choice.

What am I doing wrong - other questioners seem to get it to work but I have tried all of their solutions and they don't work for me.  I have a Galaxy G6 on Verizon with Android version 6.0.1, Kernel version 3.10.61

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out my own problem but thought it would be good to post the answer in case someone else has the same problem.  The problem was that I only had one browser, Chrome, on my device and it was, of course, registered for the http scheme.  Since it was the only one, my device treated it as the preferred app for all http schemes.  My scheme was more selective by designating a host.  The solution was to download another browser so that none were user preferred, then when Google was navigating to http://tennisrecruiting.net, my app was listed for selection.  I still don't get a transfer or selection when my mobile website is entered into Chrome but that is not surprising.